# nodejs/express/busboy - saving uploaded json data into database

Tags: node.js, express, busboy

I am using bodyboy 
https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy
upload functionality. Basically I do not need to save files, its just user uploads a file and I want to save it into my database.

So to be precise, if anyone can tell me how to console contents of file uploaded

```
req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
            console.log(fieldname)
            console.log(file)
            console.log(filename)
            console.log('readin file')
        });
```

Here how can I read the file, or even if I need anymore step?

Comment: I have updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually [connect-busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy) is a connect middleware for [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy).

You can use following sample code ,

```
    req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
          console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);
          file.on('data', function(data) {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
          });
          file.on('end', function() {
            console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
          });
    });
```

If you want to read your stream then you need to play with your stream or please try to use following way

```
   req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
               var buffer = '';
               console.log('File [' + fieldname + ']: filename: ' + filename + ', encoding: ' + encoding + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);
               file.on('data', function(data) {
                  buffer += data;
                 console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] got ' + data.length + ' bytes');
               });
               file.on('end', function() {
                 console.log('File [' + fieldname + '] Finished');
                 var val = JSON.parse(buffer);
                // use `val` here ...
               }).setEncoding('utf8');
         });
```

And make sure you have used proper headers in your request otherwise please check sample test case code to [here](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy/blob/master/test/test-types-multipart.js).

Hopes this will help you !

Comment: Thanks for your answer Santosh but this is not what I was looking for. I am upload a json file and want to read its JSON content once upload is finished.